# Python WSGI + Flask render_template - 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, mod-wsgi

I have this structure,

```
index.py
run.py
app/
  __init__.py
  routes.py
  templates/
    ...
```

index.py,

```
import os
import sys

activate_this = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/venv/Scripts/activate_this.py'
exec(open(activate_this).read(), dict(__file__ = activate_this))

# Expand Python classes path with your app's path.
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))

from run import app

#Initialize WSGI app object.
application = app
```

run.py,

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import routes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

app/routes.py,

```
from run import app
from flask import Flask, render_template

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World'

@app.route('/dave')
def myDave():
    return 'Hello World - From Dave'

@app.route('/home')
def home():
  return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
  return render_template('about.html')
```

app/`__init__.py`,

```
(blank)
```

So when I access the app with `/` I get `Hello World` which is correct, and `/dave` I get `Hello World - From Dave`

But with `/home` and `/about`, I get **500 Internal Server Error**

The log file does not give much info about the error at all,

> [Fri Aug 21 19:47:06.992431 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7036:tid
>   244] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 5872 [Fri Aug 21
>   19:47:07.257631 2015] [wsgi:warn] [pid 5872:tid 244] mod_wsgi:
>   Compiled for Python/2.7.9+. [Fri Aug 21 19:47:07.257631 2015]
>   [wsgi:warn] [pid 5872:tid 244] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.10.
>   [Fri Aug 21 19:47:07.273231 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5872:tid
>   244] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

But it seems that the module `render_template` from Flask is not loaded or not working.

Any ideas what have I done wrong?

Comment: I have set that on `app.run(debug = True)` but it is not doing anything. I still get the same 500 error as before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flask defaults to a 'templates' folder at the root path of the application.

Given your existing setup, you can instantiate your Flask app like this in `run.py`:

```
project_root = os.path.dirname(__file__)
template_path = os.path.join(project_root, 'app/templates')
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_path)
```

Comment: Except that you cannot give it a relative path. You would need to calculate an absolute path off an anchor of ``os.path.dirname(__file__)``. This is necessary as the current working directory will not be where your code is.